# How do I concat and make json in this format - google sheets and js

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using google sheets to get the data entered by the user in the rows. The user enters multiple values in a row like this. I read the data from each row and send it to the api and it needs to be the mentioned format.

> ex: haris,ryan,nicole

I want to convert it into json with the following format and append userType which is same every time for each object.

```
[{"name":"haris", "userType":"admin"},{"name":"ryan", "userType":"admin"},{"name":"nicole", "userType":"admin"}]
```

can anyone guide me on how to achieve the desired format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let row = "Haris,Ryan,Nicole";
let result = [];

row.split(',').forEach( function(value){
   result.push({'name': value, 'userType': 'admin'});
});

console.log(result);
```

Or if you don't want to use `forEach`

```js
let row = "Haris,Ryan,Nicole";
let result = [];

let rowDataAsArray = row.split(',')
for(let i=0; i<rowDataAsArray.length; i++){
    result.push({'name': rowDataAsArray[i], 'userType': 'admin'});
};

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I am getting this error "Missing ; before statement." for let result

Comment: The problem seems to be with forEach, can we use a loop instead?

Comment: Added another option without `forEach`

Comment: The 1st one itself worked after removing "=>". Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```js
let result = []
let data = "haris,ryan,nicole"
data.split(',').forEach(person => {
  result.push({
    name: person,
    userType: "admin"
  })
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: => are not working in apps script. can it be done using a loop instead?

Comment: @colen Yes. You can also achieve the same method using other kinds of iteration.